# Iterating through a list based on the value of an Id element inside the list in c#

Tags: c#

I have another question that's connected with my class:

```
public class Parent {
        public IList<ParentDetail> ParentDetails {
            get { return _ParentDetails; }
        }
        private List<ParentDetail> _ParentDetails = new List<ParentDetail>();
        public Parent() {
            this._ParentDetails = new List<ParentDetail>();
        }
    }

    public class ParentDetail {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Presently I iterate through ParentDetails and do some action for each ParentDetail. I am using MVC razor syntax so that's the reason for the @( .. etc

```
@foreach (int index in Enumerable.Range(0, Model.Parent.ParentDetails.Count()))
{
  Model.Parent.ParentDetails[@index].Id
```

This gives me the numbers 1,2,3 ... etc  IF the Ids have been assigned sequentially in the list with the first element having an Id of 1 and the second element having an Id of 2 etc.

However the Ids in my list are not assigned sequentially. I may have it like this:

```
list-element [0] has an Id of 3
list-element [1] has an Id of 4
list-element [2] has an Id of 1
list-element [3] has an Id of 2
```

What I need is something equivalent to the foreach that will let me iterate through my list based on the value of Id. Maybe I need to use the Index method to find but I don't know how to put this all into a loop.

I know some C# but this is quite far beyond me. Can anyone help out with some ideas. I hope my question makes sense.

*I will watch for comments so please just send a comment if there is something that's not clear.*

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to simply list the elements ordered by ID?

Comment: Yeah the elements need to be ordered by Id and within the loop I need to be able to show a reference to the IndexPosition of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ is the super easy solution for such cases:

```
foreach(var details in Model.Parent.ParentDetails.OrderBy(d => d.Id))
{
    // details are processed in increasing order of Id here
}
```

You will need to add the `System.Linq` namespace with `@using System.Linq` if it's not already included in your view.

**Aside**

Your existing code does things in a kind of roundabout way though. This:

```
@foreach (int index in Enumerable.Range(0, Model.Parent.ParentDetails.Count()))
{
    var x = Model.Parent.ParentDetails[@index].Id;
}
```

can also be written as

```
@foreach (var details in Model.Parent.ParentDetails)
{
    var x = details.Id;
}
```

which is the natural way of iterating over a collection, and far more preferable (unless you also need the index of each `ParentDetails` object in the collection).

Comment: This works good. However is there a way that I can within the for loop see the elemental position in the list? So that for example the first time through the loop would allow me to print "list-element [2]" Just saw your added comments. Yes I do unfortunately need the index of each ParentDetails object. I am guessing that this will not be easy to get once ordered with LINQ. If you wish I can open this up as an additional question as technically you really answered my first question and you should be credited for that. Just let me know.

Comment: @Emily: That's also easy to arrange -- but do you want the indexes in the original collection, or in the sorted one? If you want the latter then the simplest solution is to have your own `var index = 0` and `++index` just before the end of the `foreach`.

Comment: Hello Jon. I will open up as another question so I can give u credit for your work so far. What I would like is the former. I guess that is  more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

use linq as follows:

```
foreach (var res in Model.Parent.ParentDetails.Select((x,n)=> string.Format("list-element [{1}] has an Id of {0}",x.Id,n)))
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("{0}", res);
    }
```

then use the corresponding out method

Comment: But with this method I lose all other data that I have in the ParentDetail class.

Comment: @Emily: Usually you would do something like `Select((i,d)=> new { Index = i, Details = d })` and then access `res.Index` and `res.Details` inside the loop. But if all you want is a counter, I don't think this offers any practical benefit over counting manually.

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers mention LINQ, Its ok, as far, as you have Visual Studio 2088 or Higher:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb386976.aspx

If not, you could try add some internal sort operation:

```
public class Parent {

  private List<ParentDetail> _ParentDetails = new List<ParentDetail>();
  public IList<ParentDetail> ParentDetails {
    get { return _ParentDetails; }
  }

  // constructor:
  public Parent() {
    this._ParentDetails = new List<ParentDetail>();
  } // constructor

  public IList<ParentDetail> customSort() {
    Result = new List<ParentDetail>();

    // use sort code here,
    // copying item references to result list
    ...   

    return Result;
  } 
} // class
```

There are several methods to sort a list or an array, pn the web:

http://www.csharp411.com/sort-c-array-in-descendingreverse-order/

P.D. Add some comments to the constructor or destructor methods, sometimes, are difficult to read.

Comment: Considering she's using ASP.NET MVC, she's probably on .NET 3.5 or higher.