# List iteration using LINQ while showing the List position

Tags: c#

I just asked a question about my class:

```
Public class Parent {
        public IList<ParentDetail> ParentDetails {
            get { return _ParentDetails; }
        }
        private List<ParentDetail> _ParentDetails = new List<ParentDetail>();
        public Parent() {
            this._ParentDetails = new List<ParentDetail>();
        }
    }

    public class ParentDetail {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

}
```

One of the experts here (Jon) told me how I could iterate through this class in order of the ParentDetails.Id.  Here's his solution which works good. 
[Previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413023/iterating-through-a-list-based-on-the-value-of-an-id-element-inside-the-list-in-c)

```
foreach(var details in Model.Parent.ParentDetails.OrderBy(d => d.Id))
{
    // details are processed in increasing order of Id here
    // what's needed is to get access to the original order
    // information. Something like as follows:
    // select index position from ParentDetails where Id = details.ID
}
```

What I also need is within this foreach to show the index value of the list corresponding to the Id along with some other data that's in the ParentDetail class.

So for example where it says // details are processed then I want to be able to print out the index value that corresponded to the current Id in the foreach loop.

Comment: Could you link to the original question?

Comment: You don't need to initialize `_ParentDetails` twice.

Comment: @spender - yeah I also wondered about this but another user suggested it. Should I just remove " = new List<ParentDetail>()" from the line starting with private ?

Comment: @asawyer - When I said "print" I was meaning have available. Actually it's all inside an MVC web page so I need to get that original index value to put it as part of the id of a DIV.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the second [Enumerable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) method:

```
foreach(var details in Model.Parent.ParentDetails
                            .Select((value, idx) => new { Index = idx, Value = value })
                            .OrderBy(d => d.Value.Id)
                           )
{
    // details are processed in increasing order of Id here
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", details.Index, details.Value);
}
```

This is assuming you wanted the indices to be in the original order.

Comment: You're missing the `OrderBy` part of the original question.

Comment: @Travis - Hello Travis. Can you check my original question. Jon seems to have the solution I need but it doesn't show the index location that I still need.

Comment: @Travis - Thanks. I tried this out and it gives a red underline under the Id part of the last line with the OrderBy.

Comment: +1, I think this is the best approach now that I'm clearer on what she's trying to do.

Comment: It seems to be the other way round, `(value, index)`, or `Func<TSource, int, TResult>`.

Comment: @kamilk: Indeed. I wonder how this answer survived so long while being so wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular `for` for that.

```
var ordered = Model.Parent.ParentDetails.OrderBy(d => d.Id).ToList();

for(int i = 0; i < ordered.Count; i++)
{
   // details are processed in increasing order of Id here
}
```

Comment: She needs the index of the element in original ordering, not the index after it's been re-ordered, so this doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @R0MANARMY - This is correct. Jon's solution on the previous question was the closest I have seen. But still not sure how to get that original index position. I know it sounds like a strange thing to want but that's the only way I can code it. The data must be sorted in a random order, presented on screen in normal order but with access to the original position information.

Comment: @R0MANARMY and @Emily - I see, I wasn't clear on that from the question's description. In that case I'd go with Travis's answer, but if you have to, you can use the `for` approach to set up some kind of numbered list before running the `OrderBy` on it.

Comment: @Emily: Travis had most of the right solution, I edited it to include the `OrderBy` query for the sake of completeness.  However, given his solution, you should have been able to combine it with the answer you received for your previous question.  If you can't, you should take some time to learn Linq.